# finding spark scala packages

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm sure this is simpler than it looks, but I'm willing to look dumb.

I'm working my way through some Scala/Spark examples, which occasionally call for adding library dependencies, eg,

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  scalaTest % Test,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.2.0"
)
```

The question is, how do you find the appropriate names and versions for the libraries? It seems the texts all give import statements; there has to be some kind of registry or something. But where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct `version` of `library` can always search from the [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/) .If you are trying to access the `version` from `proprietary Distribution`  you need to add the `repository` of that `Distribution`.

[Cloudera repository](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_vd_cdh5_maven_repo.html)

[MapR repository](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Maven+Artifacts+for+MapR)

[hdp_maven_artifacts](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.5.0/bk_command-line-installation/content/download_hdp_maven_artifacts.html)

[image: Spark core library]